# php mysql print list with db data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to improve a php script that prints a list with db values and I need to make some complex (for me) operations to achieve what I want:

A list that prints the months and if they are paid or not, a bonus value with an extra bonus value for the first 3 ids and if the user already received it.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("  SELECT members.*, account_type.*, friends.*, friendsCount.friendID,
                                       COUNT(friendsCount.friendID) AS num_f
                                FROM members
                                INNER JOIN account_type ON account_type.id = ?
                                INNER JOIN friends ON friends.friendID = ?
                                INNER JOIN friends AS friendsCount ON friendsCount.userID = ?
                                WHERE members.id = ?")) {

    $stmt->bind_param('iiii', $_SESSION['acc_type'], $_GET['id'], $_SESSION['user_id'], $_GET['id']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_array();

    $monthNames = array("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");
    $paid = array(); //Placeholder for paid months.

    for ($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {

        $month = 'month' . $i;
        $bonus_month = 'bonus_month' . $i;

        // check if the user received the monthly bonus
        if ($row[$bonus_month] == 0) {

            // check if the friend's member account is active
            if ($row['status'] == 1) {

                // check if the friend paid the month
                if ($row[$month] == 1) {

                    $paid[] = 'Pagado';

                    // check the user account type
                    if ($row['type'] == 'Base') {

                        // TODO: check if the friend is one of the three first (special promotion)
                        // (user gets double bonus for the first three invited friends)
                        if ($row['extra'] == 1) {
                            $extra = $row['bonus'] + 5;
                            $bonus[] = $extra . '€';
                        }

                        else {
                            $bonus[] = $row['bonus'] . '€';
                        }
                    }

                    else {
                        $bonus[] = $row['bonus'] . '€';
                    }

                    $cashed[] = 'No';
                    $non_cashed[] = $bonus[];
                }

                else {
                    $paid[] = 'No Pagado';
                    $bonus[] = 'n/a';
                    $cashed[] = 'n/a';
                }
            }

            else {
                $paid[] = 'n/a';
                $bonus[] = 'n/a';
                $cashed[] = 'n/a';
            }
        }

        else {
            $paid[] = 'Pagado';
            $bonus[] = $row[$bonus_month] . '€';

            // TODO: find a way to check if user already received the bonus
            // 12 new columns? (bonus_received_month1-12)
            if (1 == 0) {
                $cashed[] = 'Si';
                $total_cashed[] = $row[$bonus_month];
            }

            else {
                $cashed[] = 'No';
                $non_cashed[] = $row[$bonus_month];
            }
        }
    }

    //Now make the HTML list

    foreach ($monthNames as $key => $month) {

        echo '
                <div class="list">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="month">' . $month . '</a></li>
                        <li><a class="status">' . $paid[$key] .'</a></li>
                        <li><a class="bonus">' . $bonus[$key] . '</a></li>
                        <li><a class="cashed">' . $cashed[$key] . '</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>';
    }
} else echo $mysqli->error;
```

Actually it's working quite well but somethings are not implemented yet:

1º The extra bonus value for the first 3 ids (not including the status 0 accounts).
2º A way to check if the user already received the bonus so can be displayed the balance and the total received:

First of, I'd like to improve the method that adds the extra bonus:

```
// this column contains 1 for the first 3 friendIDs
if ($row['extra'] == 1) {
    $extra = $row['bonus'] + 5;
    $bonus[] = $extra . '€';
} else $bonus[] = $row['bonus'] . '€';
```

To achieve this: I have to check for the first 3 friendIDs (where userID = $_SESSION[user_id]) and compare if one of those match the current $_GET['id'].

```
// the number of friends
$count = $row['num_f'];
// the current friendID
$f_id = $_GET['id'];
$match = 'the first 3 ids (with acc status 1)';

if ($count > 2 && $f_id == $match) {
    $extra = $row['bonus'] + 5;
    $bonus[] = $extra . '€';
} else $bonus[] = $row['bonus'] . '€';
```

And statistics info:

```
// not received
echo '<p>Total acumulado: ' . array_sum($non_cashed[]) . '€</p>';
// total received
echo '<p>Total recibido: ' . array_sum($total_cashed[]) . '€</p>';
```

The big problem that I'm facing here is: If one of the three first accounts is inactive (status 0) how to "take" the next one that is active...

If account 1 is inactive but 2 and 3 are not, the account number 4 should be eligible for the extra bonus. The numbers are just the order that come from "select friendID from friends where userID = ?"

I presume that I can use array_key_exists to check if the $f_id exist inside the array that contains the first 3 ids...

How can I make that? Sorry if I made some mistakes, I'm working for several hours.

The tables are:

1º members: get the friend info -> "id", "status" (0 or 1; inactive/active), "name" and "month1-12" (12 columns: 0 or 1; not paid / paid month)

2º account_type: get the user acc type and the bonus value -> "id" (members.acc_type), "type" (the type name) and "bonus" (5, 10, 15 etc...)

3º friends: get the user info related to his friend -> "friendID" (members.id, the invited user), "userID" (members.id, the user that invited a friend), "extra" (1 for the first 3 invited users and 0 for the rest; 1 is double bonus, 0 is normal bonus. This column is going to be deleted), "bonus_month1-12" (12 columns; 0 is for the current month or a future month, 1+ is the bonus the user gained this month)

And to check if the user already received the bonus, I'm thinking to add 12 more columns to know it. It'll be 0 for non-received and 1 for received, unless a better method is suggested :)

Comment: Yes ofc, I'm going to add the tables and their relationship.

Comment: You mean normalization for the way I code or for what the script does?

Comment: So I can change the numbers for letters like monthJa, monthFe, monthMa... Was that the only problem?

Comment: Could you provide a link, please?

Comment: Neither are you going to help me with my problem?

Comment: I wish you luck, but the problem's too broad for SO. Normalization is a difficult topic to get to grips with (or at least it was for me - I'm still not sure that I've really grasped it), but luckily there are vast amounts of good (and free) resources just a few clicks away. You can find them as easily as I.

Comment: Ok, but normalization for my DB structure is not going to help me for what I need to do :(